# Eclipse: Xtext and integration with Epsilon/GMF/Graphiti

Tags: eclipse, dsl, xtext, eclipse-gmf, graphiti

I want to create a DSL with graphical support in Eclipse. For the DSL I use Xtext, but cannot find good example on how to integrate the graphical part. I have not decided on one of the technologies to prove a graphical part and are prepared to use any one.

Does anybody now of good examples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That depends on how you want to design the integration. What should be the main syntax for editing, text or graphics?

Here are some examples integrating Xtext with Graphiti, GMF, and Sirius:
https://github.com/spoenemann/xtext-gef

If you don't need graphical editing, but would like to generate graphical views for your text models, you could consider [KIELER](http://rtsys.informatik.uni-kiel.de/confluence/display/KIELER/Home) (esp. the [KLighD](http://rtsys.informatik.uni-kiel.de/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=328115) component).

Comment: I looked at the xtext-gef example, but have no idea where to start. I can create separate xtext/ gmf (using EuGENia) project but how do I combine them?

Comment: The project `org.xtext.xproperties` contains example code for combining them. In this case a view is created that allows to edit parts of the model with an embedded Xtext editor, see [TextPropertiesViewPart](https://github.com/spoenemann/xtext-gef/blob/master/org.xtext.xproperties/src/org/xtext/xproperties/TextPropertiesViewPart.xtend).